# Junit test failure: HttpMessageConversion error

Tags: spring-boot, rest, junit, mockito

i am trying to write `JUnit` test case for below class using `Mockito` for rest url.

```
@Override
public void sendWebhook(WebRequest webRequest) {
    ResponseEntity<Object> webresponse = restService.sendWebhook(webRequest);
}
```

**restServiceImpl**

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Object> sendWebhook(WebRequest webRequest) {
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = null;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<webRequest> request = new HttpEntity<>(webRequest, headers);
    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(webRequest.getUrl(), HttpMethod.POST, request, Object.class);
    } catch (ResourceAccessException resourceAccessException) {

        return null;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Unit test case using `Mockito` for above class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class WebServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;
    @Autowired
    private RestService restService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendWebhookWithSuccess() throws Exception {
        /* setup mock */
        WebRequest webRequest = mock(WebRequest.class);
        Mockito.when(restService.sendWebhook(webRequest))
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.OK));

        UriComponents uriComponents =
                UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://localhost:8080/mockWeb/sendSuccessMsg").build();
        mockServer.expect(requestTo(uriComponents.toUriString())).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
                .andRespond(withSuccess("Success", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        mockServer.verify();
    }
}
```

While i run above test case i get,

```
Results :  
Tests in error: 
testSendWebhookWithSuccess » HttpMessageConversion
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

I am getting error in line

```
Mockito.when(restService.sendWebhook(webRequest))
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.OK));
```

why i am getting above error. can i know what i am missing

stackTrace below attached

```
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 38.087 sec <<< FAILURE! - in ...web.service.impl.WebServiceImplTest
    testSendWebhookWithSuccess(...service.impl.WebServiceImplTest)  Time elapsed: 0.321 sec  <<< ERROR!
    org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.mockito.internal.invocation.mockref.MockWeakReference]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.mockito.internal.invocation.mockref.MockWeakReference and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.equifax.mortgage.udm.webhook.model.WebRequest$MockitoMock$1970556850["mockitoInterceptor"]->org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor["mockHandler"]->org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler["invocationContainer"]->org.mockito.internal.stubbing.InvocationContainerImpl["invocationForStubbing"]->org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationMatcher["invocation"]->org.mockito.internal.invocation.InterceptedInvocation["mockRef"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1277)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1516)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:343)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:737)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:583)
        at ...web.service.impl.RestServiceImpl.sendWebhook(RestServiceImpl.java:50)
```

Comment: Attach an error stacktrace to question

Comment: @Alex attached stacktrace

Comment: As far as i see you are trying to call real service with mock object. So `RestTemplate` is unable fo serialize it. Besides you are trying to mock method exeuyion on real service `Mockito.when(restService.sendWebhook(webRequest))`

Comment: in addition to above comment: spring is trying to convert your webrequest with an HttpMessageConverter when you want to send that with your RestTemplate. This is typically so you can pass in objects and they are for example converted to json. Would it be able to use a normal pojo instead of a WebRequest as method parameter?

Answer (score 2):

It means your mock object is going through proper jackson deserialization when you can only do that with a real object.
In your case, I think it's the `new ResponseEntity<Object>(...)` that's the problem: it's not a real serializable object.

Create something concrete for your `thenReturn(thisBetterBeSerializable)` because it's clearly going through jackson somewhere in that nested service call.

I got that exact exception ("No serializer found for class org.mockito.internal.invocation.mockref.MockWeakReference and ...") when I created a mock object as a response in a spring controller test:

I had this (paraphrased)

```java
@MockBean
private MyService myService;

@Test
public void test_200Returned() throws Exception {
  MyRealResponseType mockResponse = Mockito.mock(MyRealResponseType.class); // WRONG!
  when(myService.myMethod(any(MyRequest.class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);

  this.mockMvc.perform(post("/my/service/api")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Everything worked fine until my controller class, the one that serves /my/service/api, tries to return an object after calling `myService.myMethod` to get it. The mockResponse object gets returned (as planned) but Jackson can't deal with it.

I fixed my problem with by replacing my `Mockito.mock` line with:

```java
  MyRealResponseType mockResponse = new MyRealResponseType(); // RIGHT!
  mockResponse.setSomeNeededPropertyJustInCase("someValue");
...
```

Then all worked and my test passed.

Your case is slightly different, but I suspect if you create a real object to pass into `thenReturn`, your problems will go away.